# Random number game isnt functioning

Tags: javascript, html

I just need help with some simple code, I think it may be my id's but I am not sure so any help would be useful.

```html
<script>
  function guessNumber() {
    var playerGuess = document.getElementById("guessInput").value;
    var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    if (playerGuess == computerChoice) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You win: both you and 
      the computer picked "+playerGuess;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Too bad,  you picked “  +
        playerGuess + " and the computer picked " + computerChoice;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Guessing Game
    <h1>
      <br>
      <h2>The computer will choose a number between 1 and 100
        <h2>
          <br>
          <h2>You have to try and guess what it picked
            <h2>
              <br>
              <span>Input your guess</span>
              <input id="guessInput">
              <br>
              <button onclick="guessNumber()">Guess</button>
              <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: "_isnt functioning_" isn't a good problem description. _What_ is not functioning? What did you expect it to do? What did it actually do that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `JS` function isn't closed properly with an ending bracket `}`, causing syntax errors. Secondly, you have a character double quote that isn't supported in the code `“` instead of using `"`, which is also causing runtime errors. Also, you aren't closing your header tags (`<h1>, <h2>`) etc.

```js
function guessNumber() {

  var playerGuess = document.getElementById("guessInput").value;
  if (playerGuess == "" || playerGuess < 1 || playerGuess > 100) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please enter a number 1 - 100";
    return;
  }

  var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

  if (playerGuess == computerChoice) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
      "You win: both you and the computer picked " + playerGuess;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
      "Too bad,  you picked " + playerGuess + " and the computer picked " + computerChoice;
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Guessing Game
</h1>
<br/>
<h2>The computer will choose a number between 1 and 100
</h2>
<br/>
<h2>You have to try and guess what it picked
</h2>
<br/>
<span>Input your guess</span>
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" id="guessInput" />
<br/>
<button onClick="guessNumber();">Guess</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors. Other than that it works fine:

- line 6 needs a closing quotation and line 7 needs an opening quotation

  - `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You win: both you and 
    the computer picked "+playerGuess;` becomes `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You win: both you and "
    "the computer picked "+playerGuess;`
- line 9 needs a proper double quote, not the “ character

  - `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Too bad,  you picked “` becomes `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Too bad,  you picked "`
- line 12 needs a closing bracket for your function guessNumber()

  - It should be `function guessNumber() { <your code> }` instead of `function guessNumber() { <your code> ...` no closing bracket